# How to Insert UserControl TextBox to DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls, rows, datagridviewcolumn

In Sql Server 2005, In Form Load I write this Code. txtPrprCase is a UserControl and validates First Character to Capital. How to i add this Control to DataGridView. I try the Following Code. But it  does not Work.

```
ciscontrols.txtPrprCase txt = new ciscontrols.txtPrprCase();
        txt.Name = "Customer Name";
        this.dataGridView2.RowCount = 1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = txt;
        }
```

and the following code works the validation

```
ciscontrols.txtPrprCase txt = new ciscontrols.txtPrprCase();
this.dataGridView2.Rows.add(txt);
```

it works but it does not contain column header and row header...

Answer (score 1):

[This is going to be perfect for you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx)